# Add control to logical-tree parent

Tags: wpf

My Main Window is a relatively simple `DockPanel`:

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <!--Bottom row--> 
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <!--Detector Indicator-->
            <views:DetectorIndicatorView DataContext="{Binding DetectorViewModel}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            <!--Logo-->
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"                     Source="/Resources/Images/Logo.png"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
        
    <!--Main display-->
    <views:TabControlView DataContext="{Binding TabsViewModel}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Inside the `TabControl`'s `SelectedContent` there's a viewmodel for each tab, and each one of those can host a variety of viewmodels.

At one point, the tree basically looks like:

```xml
<MainWindow>
    <TabControl>
        <ExamTab>
            <EditExam/>
        </ExamTab>
    </TabControl>
</MainWindow>
```

And on the `EditExam` page, I want a toolbar to appear in the `Bottom row` of the `MainWindow`. The toolbar buttons will be bound to commands ont he `EditExamViewModel`.

Is there a way I can "inject" an inner control like this into the "outer template" (i.e., the main window)?

The only way I can think of is to take the bottom row out of the `MainWindow` and paste it into each individual view, identical except for the one instance in `EditExamView`. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can "inject" an inner control like this into the "outer template" (i.e., the main window)?

No, there is not, at least not in XAML.

You could it programmatically by for example getting a reference to the parent window in the view using the `Window.GetWindow` method, or by raising an event or send a message from the "tab" view model to the window view model or window using an [event aggregator](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) or a [messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is common in modern applications. Even menus are often swapped depending on the active view. However, there is no *built-in* way of doing this in XAML or WPF. The easiest way to solve this is

> [...] to take the bottom row out of the MainWindow and paste it into each individual view, identical except for the one instance in EditExamView. [...]

The hardest way is to develop all that is needed for this scenario yourself including

- Creating views and view models as data context dynamically
- A concept to define areas where your views should be injected
- Swapping in and out dependent views including their view models
- Communication between views for synchronization or updating
- Managing activation and deactivation of your exam tabs
- Custom commands that you can wire accross views to your tab view
- ...

This is a lot of code that you might not be able to write on your own. But you are not alone, because there are application frameworks intended to bridge the gap between UI frameworks and your code like [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/) or [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/). These frameworks enable you to skip a lot of boilerplate code and provide services and mechanisms for various issues, but at the cost of learning them and some customization to fit your needs.

Prism as an example provides the following solutions to the issues above

- A dependency injection container
- Regions that define areas within your application
- A rich region navigation service
- An event aggregator for communication
- Region adapters with active awareness
- Composite Commands that can be used across views
- ...

This looks overwhelming at first, but the more you become familiar with a framework of your choice, the easier application development gets, as you will reuse concepts and components. At this point I recommend you not to *re-invent the wheel*. At first, you could use the easy solution and start getting familiar with any framework and gradually migrate your application.

Answer (score 0):

So actually I’ve come up with a pretty good and simple solution, which is simply:

```xml
<ContentControl Content=“{Binding TabControlViewModel.Tabs[SelectedIndex].CurrentViewModel.ToolbarViewModel}”/>
```

If the current view model doesn’t have a toolbar view model then it’ll just evaluate to null and show nothing. Then I can define a data template for ToolbarViewModel and we’re all set.

If I wanted to enable various pages to have different things in the bottom bar, I could have ToolbarViewModel be some more general type (and probably a different name), possibly whatever my view model base is, and then any page’s VM could be any type of view model I want, and I could set the DataTemplate. The only caveat would be I don’t think I could have more than one template for any given VM, but I could get around that by creating simple subclasses for each way I’d want it to render so I could have different templates.